# Android v3 Cast SDK crashes

Tags: google-play-services, chromecast, android-cast-api, castcompanionlibrary

I recently upgraded our app to use the v3 Cast SDK provided through google play services. I now get the following exception on devices with google play services that are under 9.1.0

```
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznm.zzbg(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznm.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.UIMediaController.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

This is reproducible in the [Cast sample app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) using a device with play services < 9.1.0

Comment: Do you mean [9.0.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90)? I think Google Play Service below 9.0.1 does not support Android Cast SDK v3 as in the [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#2) - "google-play-services_lib revision 30 or later".

Comment: probably is that your device does not have google play services (as in genymotion) or it is outdated and you need to update it.